# React: How do I pass a returned function value to a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return, gatsby, react-props

new to react so this is probably very obvious but I have a function that calculates distance between the user and the lat,lng of the component (from the state) and then returns the value with `returnDistance()`.

```
export default class Space extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const userLat = this.props.userLat,
        userLng = this.props.userLng;

        let lat = this.props.node.latitude,
            lng = this.props.node.longitude;

        function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
            var R = 6371; // km
            var dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1);
            var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);
            var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
            var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

            var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            var d = R * c;
            return d;
        }

        // Converts numeric degrees to radians
        function toRad(Value) {
            return Value * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        function returnDistance() {
            return getDistance(userLat, userLng, lat, lng).toFixed(1);
        }

        return (
            <Component>
                {userLat ?
                <ComponentDistance>
                    {returnDistance()}
                    <span>km</span>
                </ComponentDistance>
                : null }
            </Component>
        )
    }
}
```

How do I pass the value of `returnDistance()` to the parent component when I can't setState or props within render?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a prop called something like `onCalculateDistance` and, in the child, do this:

```
function returnDistance() {
        const dist = getDistance(userLat, userLng, lat, lng).toFixed(1);
        this.props.onCalculateDistance(dist);
        return dist;
    }
```

And then in the parent, you can do this:

```
distanceChange(dist) {
       // whatever you want, for example
     this.setState({dist});
}

render() {
  return (<Space onCalculateDistance=(this.distanceChange)/>)
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that that will run every time Space is re-rendered, so you may want to do something to check that the value has changed since last time before doing anything expensive with it. Probably just directly calling 'setstate' is a bad idea without checking if it's changed

Comment: Thanks! However, I get the error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". And if I add `this.onCalculateDistance = this.onCalculateDistance.bind(this);` to the constructor, I then get "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined". Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: post your whole parent and child code in a jsfiddle @mckeever02 and we can look.

Comment: Thanks @TKoL. Probably easier if I just paste them into gists? 

Here's the parent index.js : https://gist.github.com/mckeever02/552149b896ce4638cfa107e21790ca11

And the child component: https://gist.github.com/mckeever02/4dceae17b857b99b2282dce7c0d3f94f

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would keep the `returnDistance()` function in the parent component if you need access to its result there. Then you pass it down in the props of the component it will be called in.

Comment: If the variables `lat` and `lng` are defined within the child - how do I get around them being undefined?

```function returnDistance() {
   return getDistance(userLat,userLng,lat,lng).toFixed(1);
 }
```